# Windows file dialog broken, shows only contained folders, not files

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

My father has a windows 10 machine. We have stumbled on a peculiar behaviour of the File dialog. For instance, when attempting to select a folder for the desktop wallpapers (`Settings > Personalisation > Choose albums for your slideshow > Browse`), the dialog opens, but the currently selected folder's contents are not shown, unless they are directories. Instead, the text `No items match your search` is shown (as if something had been entered in the search box without results)
This is what I see then:

[image]

The same happens with a Save dialog, e.g. in Firefox, so it would appear to be a global issue, but other apps (like Snipping tool) do not show this behaviour.

Folders display in Explorer just fine.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Browse dialog in the Personalize window (by design) allows you to choose the folder that contains all the images but not the individual files.

If you want to pick specific set of files for desktop slideshow, you need to use the classic wallpaper panel. It can be accessed by executing this command from the Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)

```
control.exe /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
```

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure it used to be different. It makes sense, but knowing the contents can be relevant for the selection and I seem to remember it being that way, but maybe that's wrong. Also the text displayed does not really make sense. And also Firefox for instance has the same problem. Clearly, individual files are relevant here. I'm not a frequent win user, but I think it used to display the files as well.